# issue with time in end , of an event , in fullcalendar

Tags: events, time, fullcalendar

i made several tests and this behaviour is strange :

```
    events: [
        {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2018-02-05',
            end    : '2018-02-07 08:00:00'

        }
    ]
```

and the event appears as a 2 days event ( 5 and 6 ) ( bad behaviour for my project )

```
    events: [
        {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2018-02-05',
            end    : '2018-02-07 09:00:00'

        }
    ]
```

and the event appears as a 3 days event ( 5,6 and 7 ) ( good behaviour for my project )

there's something around 9 o'clock i dont know what, how can i fix it ??

Comment: It's probably this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/nextDayThreshold/

Comment: ty !! i didnt see :)

Answer (score 2):

In the fullCalendar options it's possible to add

```
nextDayThreshold: "00:00:00"
```

and the behaviour around 9am disappears.

The default value for nextDayThreshold is 9am.

Comment: Correct, but just to add, it's not "strange" behaviour, it's behaviour clearly documented in the nextDayThreshold documentation. I have edited your answer slightly to clarify that and also fix the formatting and grammar. I also removed "I found" because you didn't find it - I did (comment on the question).

Answer (score 1):

thx again for the indication about nextDayThreshold

nevertheless it seems there is a strange behaviour with 00:00:00 only this value, i mean :

```
events: [
    {
        title  : 'event2',
        start  : '2018-02-05',
        end    : '2018-02-07 01:00:00'

    }
],
```

nextDayThreshold: "01:00:00"

gives a 3-days large event on calendar ( normal ), but

```
events: [
    {
        title  : 'event2',
        start  : '2018-02-05',
        end    : '2018-02-07 00:00:00'

    }
],
```

nextDayThreshold: "00:00:00"

gives only a 2-days large event , alas...